# The incomplete representation of the information given by the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I created an action to return all controllers in my project.

when I debug that it shows me 4 items, but when using the postman and swagger it just shows only one item.

Controller :

```
  [HttpGet("GetControllerList")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ControllerViewModel>> Get()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var controller=await iMVCService.GetControllerDescovery(asm); ;
        return controller;
    }
```

and info in post man :

```
{"data":[{"areaName":null,"controllerAttributes":{"name":"مدیریت دسته بندی ها","shortName":null,"description":null,"prompt":null,"groupName":null,"resourceType":null
```

**Edit :**

MVCSErive :

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<ControllerViewModel>> GetControllerDescovery(Assembly assemblies)
    {
        var controllers = assemblies.GetExportedTypes()
                                                .Where(t => typeof(ControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                                                .Select(t => new ControllerViewModel
                                                {
                                                    ControllerAttributes = t.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(),
                                                    ControllerName = t.Name,
                                                    ControllerId = $"{t.Namespace} : {t.Name}"
                                                })
                                                .Where(x => x != null)
                                                .ToList();
        return  controllers;
    }
```

and my View Model :

```
   public class ControllerViewModel
{
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns the list of the Controller's Attributes.
    public DisplayAttribute ControllerAttributes { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns the `DisplayNameAttribute` value
    public string ControllerDisplayName { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     It's set to `{AreaName}:{ControllerName}`
    public string ControllerId { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Return ControllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
}
```

what might be the problem???

Comment: what does `GetControllerDescovery` do did you try debugging the returned values in ` var controller` ?

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil yes . i debug that and work correctly but in post man not show correct

Comment: Could you please show us your postman request and implementation of `GetControllerDescovery`. What is `IMvcAssemby` ?

Comment: Is `GetControllerDiscovery` *your* method? I ask because the only two places on the whole internet where I can find it is in your two questions here on Stack Overflow. As such, you need to post more code, otherwise all we can say is that you have a bug somewhere.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen its just this code . it find 4 controller and when i using the breakpoint int this line `return controller` it show me 4 controller and info of them . but in post man it show me one of then and incomplete it .

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i edit the question

Comment: The method is returning a task, not a collection, could it be that you have serialized the task, not the collection?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i change that but still have that problem

Comment: Please show us how did you change the code without Task

Comment: @RomanMarusyk i type with Task and Without Task

Comment: ok, but I asked show us the code